# Conditional Grouping Records

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the MAX `operation_date` record for `PAYMENT` just before the `REINSURER` operation. Subgrouping the records by payment or reinsurer. The data looks as follows:

```
operation_date | operation
05-17-2012        PAYMENT
05-18-2012        PAYMENT
05-21-2012        PAYMENT
05-25-2012        REINSURER
05-30-2012        PAYMENT
06-07-2012        PAYMENT
06-08-2012        PAYMENT
06-08-2012        REINSURER
06-11-2012        PAYMENT
06-22-2012        REINSURER
07-09-2012        PAYMENT
07-17-2012        REINSURER
07-23-2012        PAYMENT
07-24-2012        PAYMENT
07-27-2012        REINSURER
07-30-2012        PAYMENT
10-31-2012        PAYMENT
11-01-2012        PAYMENT
```

And I need this output:

```
operation_date | operation
05-21-2012        PAYMENT
05-25-2012        REINSURER
06-08-2012        PAYMENT
06-08-2012        REINSURER
06-11-2012        PAYMENT
06-22-2012        REINSURER
07-09-2012        PAYMENT
07-17-2012        REINSURER
07-24-2012        PAYMENT
07-27-2012        REINSURER
11-01-2012        PAYMENT
```

I have been playing around with the analytic functions with no success. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Can you include the queries that you have tried?  The ones with the analytic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use cumulative sum to generate groups and then perform aggregation on that.

```
select max(operation_date) as operation_date,
    operation
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when operation = 'REINSURER' then 1 else 0 end) over (
            order by operation_date, operation
            ) as grp
    from t
    where operation in ('REINSURER', 'PAYMENT')
    ) t
group by grp,
    operation
order by operation_date
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/PBUCL4104)

Comment: Brilliant logic to create group. +1

Comment: this assumes the max operation_date in each group is for the `PAYMENT` row. if it is not, you may get incorrect results, i.e. a non `PAYMENT` row.

Comment: @vkp - I am grouping by operation. If there *is* a non payment row other than REINSURER, then that too will come in the result. Which can be easily fixed by filtering to allow only PAYMENT and REINSURER

Comment: yes..you have to filter only for those rows in my opinion.

Comment: filtering *not* in the sub-query. but after that.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thak you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need lag/lead analytic functions over aggregate analytic function.

```
select * from ( 
    select a.*,lag(operation_date) over(order by operation_date) p_opr_dt,
      lag(operation) over(order by operation_date) p_opr from operations a 
) where operation = 'REINSURER' and p_opr = 'PAYMENT'
```

Comment: I need the payment records as rows. Im going to run several processes each time I have an operation date. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JohnCardenas do you need both payment and reinsurer record as well or just the payment record before reinsurer. You just want to switch to "lead" analytic function.